# Is there a simple algorithm that can find the envelope of several circles?

Tags: geometry

Given a number of points on a 2d surface and radiuses for these points I can easily paint circles for them. What I need is an algorithm that only paints the envelope (right word for what I am looking for?) or outer bound of these combined circles. Additionally a second set of circles can 'encroach' on these circles, resulting in a kind of 'border'.

[Image of what I am looking for](https://pasteboard.co/IC5UXgC.png)

Comment: You did not specify how the "encroaching" works.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to draw the outline of the union of the disks is to

- fill all disks in yellow, then
- fill all disks in white with a smaller radius.

This can be adapted to the "encroached" circles, provided you only fill the remaining portions of the disks. Unfortunately, in a general setting finding the remaining portions can be an uneasy geometric problem.

---

There is an alternative approach which can work in all cases:

- fill an image with zeroes, then for all disks fill every pixel with the value of the distance to the circumference (maximum at the center), but only keep the highest value so far.
- while you do this, fill a second image with the color of the disk that achieved that highest value. (Initialize the image with the background color.)

At the end of this process, the first image will represent a "terrain" made of intersecting cones; and for every point of the terrain, you will know the color.

- finally, color the pixels that have a height smaller than the desired stroke width, using the color map.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the drawing in two steps.

1) Draw the outline using the following method: For each point, draw a circle using your favorite circle-drawing method, but before drawing a pixel, ensure that it is not contained inside any other circle. Do this for every point and you will get your outline.

2) Draw the borders between different sets using the following method: For each pair of points from different sets, calculate the two intersection points of the circles. If there is an intersection, the border can be drawn as a segment joining these two points. However, you have to make two lines, one for circle A, and another for circle B. To draw the line for circle A, slightly offset the segment towards point A. Then, use your favorite line-drawing method, but before drawing a pixel, ensure that it is closer to point A that any other point of the opposite set. After drawing the line, repeat the process for circle B. Note that both segment are not guaranteed to be the same length since the asymmetry of the points of the different sets. It will, however, always form a closed shape when all outlines and borders are drawn.